# How can i refresh only data in table with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have page with data table and i need to refresh only data in table and i use bootstrap datatable to sort but when i use refresh data in my page will can not use bootstrap to sort data. How can i fix it?

this my code for get data to refresh

```
    $request = $this->m_request->get_request_list();

    $row = '';
    $row .= '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="datatable">';
    $row .= '<thead>';
    $row .= '<tr>';
    $row .= '<td>Start</td>';
    $row .= '<td>End</td>';
    $row .= '<td>Type</td>';
    $row .= '</tr>';
    $row .= '</thead>';
    $row .= '<tbody>';
    foreach ($re as $r){
        $row .= '<tr id="sh">';
        $row .= '<td>'.$r->date_start.'</td>';
        $row .= '<td>'.$r->date_end.'</td>';
        $row .= '<td>'.$r->leave_type.'</td>';
        $row .= '</tr>';
    }
    $row .= '</tbody>';
    $row .= '</table>';
    echo $row;
```

and this is my javascript to get data to show

```
var $container = $("#show_data");
$container.load("<?php echo site_url('request/get')?>");
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container.load('<?php echo site_url('request/get')?>');
}, 3000);
```

if i show table in view page the data will can not refresh to get data and if i call table in controller page i will can not use bootstrap datatable.
Please help. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinitialize you datatable after each ajax success

```
var $container = $("#show_data");
$container.load("<?php echo site_url('request/get')?>",function(){ $('table').DataTable();});

var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container.load("<?php echo site_url('request/get')?>",function(){ $('table').DataTable();});
}, 3000);
```

Comment: thank you, it's impossible if i set auto reload page when have new data and if not have new data not reload page.

Comment: why reload the page? ajax is for not reloading the page, you defeat the purpose of ajax